# Use an Image from Drive for a button in Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script

My apologies if this is answered someplace already.  I looked but maybe had bad search terms.

How can I use an image from Google Drive as a button in a Google Apps Script which is serving HTML as a web app?

I know that I have to use the following to get an image to show, such as a banner:
In HTML File:

```
    <script>
//for showing the image
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler( function(bytes){ showImage(bytes) })
  .loadImageBytes();

  function showImage(bytes){
    document.getElementById("headerimage").src = "data:image/png;base64," + bytes; 
    $("#headerimage").fadeIn(2500);
  }</script>
```

and on the server side:

```
//For displaying an image from our Google Drive
function loadImageBytes(){
 //https://drive.google.com/a/boxwood.org/file/d/1ewu8FAmyIGooL4cXH4ki6CuVKE5v_4HC/view?usp=sharing
  var id = "1ewu8FAmyIGooL4cXH4ki6CuVKE5v_4HC"
  var bytes = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes();
  return Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
}
```

But how would I set an image for a button in a stylesheet?

```
/* Edit Buttons */
.edit_button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-image: url( 'https://drive.google.com/a/boxwood.org/file/d/1sR7PUHUiTlcWarlm4Ks-SXF2j5EUACwe' );
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: From your question, it seems that you are using the file in ``boxwood.org``. So how about the direct link like ``https://drive.google.com/a/boxwood.org/uc?id=1sR7PUHUiTlcWarlm4Ks-SXF2j5EUACwe``? And please share it as James D says. I'm not sure about the detail of your environment. So if this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: It is shared to Anyone with the link with View rights.  That link works for me.  The end users will be domain users, so if the link as shown does not work for others outside the domain it is not a huge problem.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using an image from drive like this you need to append the file ID to the URL: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=

The image must be shared 'anyone with the link can view'

Comment: Thank you, @Jame D I had seen elsewhere that this was not working but perhaps that was for images used such as an image showing on a page vs a background image for something like a button as the method given which did work is what I had to use for a banner.  Also, as per above, the image is shared for Anyone with the link as well as all of our domain  users having access, so that bit is not a problem.